# Ansible variable in action (get first ip of second interface) with jinja

Tags: ansible

I need to get the first IP of the second interface on my server (within a jinja variable).

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook testing
  hosts: all
  become: true
  
  tasks:
  - name: Debug
    debug:
      msg:
      - "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'][0]]['ansible_host'] }}"
      - "{{ ansible_interfaces | difference(['lo',ansible_default_ipv4.alias]) | first }}"
      - "{% set sync_iface = ansible_interfaces | difference(['lo',ansible_default_ipv4.alias]) | first %}"
```

To get the second interface, I use the 2nd debug line.
The 3rd line is to set this interface as a variable, because I read somewhere that I can then use the following to get the ip. But this does not work.

```yaml
      - vars['ansible_'~sync_iface].ipv4.address
```

Maybe it's just that my syntax is wrong but I'm not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking for granted your above example expression gives the expected result, here is a minimal playbook with the correct syntax to declare a reusable variable.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  
  vars:
    second_interface: "{{ ansible_interfaces | difference(['lo',ansible_default_ipv4.alias]) | first }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Display second interface details for server
      debug:
        msg: "{{ second_interface_ip }}"
```

There are other options to declare the variable. See [Where to set variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#where-to-set-variables) for more information.

I used `msg` with a jinja2 expression in the `debug` task since you mentionned it in your question. Meanwhile you can replace that task with

```yaml
    - name: Display second interface details for server
      debug:
        var: second_interface_ip
```

which gives slighly the same result and will not end with an error in case the variable content cannot be parsed (e.g. undefined dictionary key, empty result from `difference` ...)

Once the variable is defined, you can use it in any other task, including inside a full jinja2 template that you would render with the [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html).